# JQuery loading from the current html another html and check a submit of this one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am triying to check if a submit is clicked in some other html in order to load an image by ajax in the current html, but I think that submit can not be located.

**Ajax function to put image:**

```
function sync_vitrasa(id){
        $.ajax({

             url: "/vitrasa_state/",
             type:"GET",
             data: {
               id: id,
             },success: function( data ) {
                id="#zv"+id;
                $(id).html(data);
             }
       });

    }
```

**Ajax function that call the last one and check the submit in another HTML:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url : '/vitrasa/',
        success : function(data){
            if($('#sub2').click()){
                    alert( "calling Ajax." );
                    sync_vitrasa(2);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**PD:** the url vitrasa_state call a controller function(in django views.py) that returns the image or not

Comment: which function is run when "submit" is clicked?

Could you update with the HTML for the submit button?

Comment: I would like to run the alert in order to check the response and sync_vitrasa() to charge image in the HTML, thanks

Comment: `if($('#sub2').click())` makes no sense. You're triggering the click event of "sub2" here, and then trying to make an if based on the return value of the click function (probably will end up truthy most of the time). The wording isn't clear enough for me to determine exactly what you're trying to achieve, if you're trying to detect a "click" or "submit" event, then either (a) handle the event you want, or (b) if it's already handled and you want to detect it elsewhere, make it emit a custom event and handle that.